# laravel 8 session doesn't save data

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to save an array for checkout but when i print session it gives null

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use App\Orders;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Cart;
use Carbon\Carbon;
public function setAmountForCheckout()
    {
        if(session()->has('coupon'))
        {
            session()->put('checkout',[
                'discount'=>$this->discount,
                'subtotal'=>$this->subtotalAfterDiscount,
                'total'=>$this->totalAfterDiscount,
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            session()->put('checkout',[
                'discount'=>0,
                'tax'=>Cart::instance('cart')->tax(),
                'subtotal'=>Cart::instance('cart')->subtotal(),
                'total'=>Cart::instance('cart')->total(),
            ]);    
            session()->save();
        }
        
    }
public function placeOrder(Request $request)
    {
        dd(session()->get('checkout'));
        $this->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required|min:4|string',
            'Phone_number' => 'required|digits:11'
        ]);
        $order=new Orders();
        $order->user_id=Auth::id();
        $order->cust_name=$this->first_name;
        $order->phone=$this->Phone_number;
        $order->subtotal=session()->get('checkout')['subtotal'];
        $order->discount=session()->get('checkout')['discount'];
        $order->total=session()->get('checkout')['total'];
        $order->status='ordered';
        $order->is_shipping=$this->haveShipping ? 1:0;
        foreach(Cart::instance('cart')->content() as $items)
        {   
            $orderItem= new OrderItems();
            $orderItem->product_id=$items->id;
            $orderItem->price=$item->price;
            $orderItem->order_id=$order->id;
            $orderItem->quantity=$item->qty;
            $orderItem->save();
        }
        if($this->haveShipping)
        {
            $this->validate([
                'Address'=>'required|min:4',
                'shipping_fee'=>'required|numeric'
            ]);
            $order->address=$this->Address;
            $order->delivery=$this->shipping_fee;
        }
        $order->save();
        Cart::instance('cart')->destroy();
        session()->forget('checkout');
    }
```

when i remove dd it gives me the error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
I'm trying to find what's wrong with the session.
also i have checked the cart if it works or not but i found that it works well and delivers data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
session()->save();
```

This is not needed as per https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data

Comment: I remove it but the problem still